# Cron task does not work

Tags: debian, cron, python, docker, syslog

I am developing a backup script in my NAS running a docker container. Inside my container I have cron running with this /etc/crontab:

```
root@backups-nas:/code# cat /etc/crontab
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

0 * * * * root /code/backup.sh
```

I have also installed syslog-ng, so I can look for logs in /var/log/syslog, where my task appears:

```
root@backups-nas:/code# tail -f /var/log/syslog 
==> /var/log/syslog <==
Mar 24 19:00:01 backups-nas CRON[9250]: (root) CMD (/code/backup.sh)
```

The content of my script is this:

```
root@backups-nas:/code# cat backup.sh
#!/bin/bash
python3 /code/backup.py all >> /code/log/$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y).log
```

But when it's o'clock no new log writter in /code/log/$(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y).log and the task is not completed. If I try to execute manually the line of /etc/crontab it works.

What do you think is happening? Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I edited backup.py, starting like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from sys import argv
import datetime
```

If I run the script directly works, but cron doesn't run it, although the line in /var/log/syslog.

Comment: What's the path to the `python3` interpreter on your system?

Comment: @Kusalananda The path is: /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: You're trying to use `python3` as the interpreter for `backup.sh` -- something that looks like (and whose filename suggests is) a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

In your system crontab file, you set the value of the `PATH` variable to `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`.  This does *not* include the path to your `python3` interpreter, which [you say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574716/cron-task-does-not-work#comment1069961_574716) is located at `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

This means that you will need to do one of the following things:

- Add `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH`.  You can do that in the crontab file by modifying the `PATH=` line (this would affect all jobs in the system's crontab file), or in the `backup.sh` script with `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`, before calling your Python backup script.
- Use the Python interpreter with an explicit path when you call your Python script, as in

  ```
  /usr/local/bin/python3 /code/backup.py all >> "/code/log/$(date +%d-%m-%Y).log"
  ```

  (note that the `%` characters do not have to be escaped here).
- Rely on the interpreter specified in the `#!`-line of the `/code/backup.py` script by not specifying an explicit interpreter at all:

  ```
  /code/backup.py all >> "/code/log/$(date +%d-%m-%Y).log"
  ```

  This relies on the first line of the `backup.py` script being `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`, and that the script is executable (`chmod +x /code/backup.py`).

Out of these variants, the "best" (personal opinion) is the last variation.

Comment: I have just edited my post, please check

Comment: @ÁngelCarlosdelPozoMuela Yeah, I said to make sure that the _Python_ script had that `#!`-line, not the shell script that you call from the crontab. The shell script already had the correct `#!`-line (calling `bash`).

Comment: True! Just edited again the post with no success.

Comment: @ÁngelCarlosdelPozoMuela And both the shell script and the Python script are executable?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved! I could debug it adding a log in tmp not inside my .sh, in my /etc/crontab.

The problem was simple: I was using a relative path instead of an absolute. But the echo inside my .sh didn't show anything.